Unable to build next.js 14.1.0
I am trying to make the next.js application build. I run the command npm run build
then I get the following errors
Do I need to resolve all these warnings one by one ? or there any other solution available to ignore these warnings
this is my next.config.mjs file
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
//  skipTrailingSlashRedirect: true,
//  trailingSlash: true,
//  output: 'export',

api: {
  bodyParser: {
    sizeLimit: "20mb",
  },
},

  images: {
    domains: ['20.40.101.154'],
  },

};
  
export default nextConfig;



The api key in your config might be the issue here, I don't think it's an option you can change that way.
Based on :

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverActions
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js

Maybe try to change this key with
experimental: {
    serverActions: {
      bodySizeLimit: '20mb',
    },
 },

The warnings are not vital to be fixed but it might be a better idea to fix them than to hide them. Even more when the fixes are written in the warning messages and are easy to make. :)
Let me know if it worked !
